# Solaris 10 mount windows nfs share

Tags: windows, share, solaris, nfs

Im trying to mount a windows NFS Share to my solaris server.

On my solaris server it is joined to my windows Active Directory server using LDAP and kerberos, I can login find with AD Users.

Now im asking the question of how I mount that users windows home area on my solaris server.

I have tried to use Windows NFS Server but when I mount it in solaris is says permission denied.

The window share is set to allow ALL_MACHINES and everyone is allowed full control

Any ideas?

Comment: What does `showmount -e windows.server.host.name` show?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Hi it just shows `/Profiles (everyone)`

Comment: Can you mount `/Profiles`?

Comment: I can mount the share but when I try and access it, it says permission denied. I have a AD user of `Test1(10001), UnixUsers(20001)` I have tested this user on windows side and I can write and create folders in the Profiles folder.

Comment: When `/Profiles` is mounted on the client, what do its permissions look like?

Comment: I use `mount -o vers=3 srv1:/Profiles /mnt` to mount the share when I do `ls -l /` It says `./mnt: permission denied ..`

Comment: @AndrewHenle any other suggestions ?